# Что лучше, .getText.toString(), или отдельный класс с Getter-Setter?

Tags: java, android

Интересует как в идеале писать, допустим:

```
 @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("email", editText.getText().toString());
```

Или лучше создать отдельный класс с геттерами-сеттерами и ссылаться на него:

```
@Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("email",class_example.toString());
```

В первом случае замечал иногда утечки, какие-то не понятные, как предпочитают вообще писать профи?

Comment: В целом правильным считается обращение через Getter-Setter для любых объектов кроме базовых (число и т.п.) Это связано в основном (на мой взгляд) с применением паттерна-программирования* Model-View-Presenter (например) Этот паттерн и накладывает ограничение-на-стиль-программирования; Так в указанном примере мы должны были бы вызвать что-то типа: Presenter.PushEvent("GetStringValue", "editText"); а из Presenter вызвать Getter для editText